# Can't create 2 tables

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to dynamically create a table based on user input, and it's working perfectly, however, it is supposed to make a table based on the `super` input the user gives, so if `super` is `2`, then it loops to create 2 tables. However it is doing everything but that, because if it was, then the tables would be next to each other, not one below each other as I have set the CSS that way. Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function createTable()
{
var num_ports = document.getElementById('ports').value;
var num_super = document.getElementById('super').value;
var num_rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
var num_cols = document.getElementById('cols').value;
var tbody = '';
var colStart = num_cols / num_super;
var y = 1;
for( var i = 1; i <= num_super; i++){
    var theader = '<div style="margin:0 auto;"><table border="1" style="border:1px solid black; float:left;">\n';
        for(u = 1; u <= num_rows; u++){
          tbody += '<tr>';
            for( var j = 0; j < colStart; j++)
            {
            tbody += '<td style="width:80px; height:70px;">';
            tbody += '<sub style="float:right; position:relative; top:24px; z-index:11;  ">' + y + '</sub>';
            tbody += '</td>';
            y++;
            }
    tbody += '</tr>\n';
}
var tfooter = '</table></div>';
document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;
}
}
</script>

<body>
<form name="tablegen">
<label>Ports: <input type="text" name="ports" id="ports"/></label><br />
<label>Super Columns: <input type="text" name="super" id="super"/></label><br />
<label>Rows: <input type="text" name="rows" id="rows"/></label><br />
<label>Columns: <input type="text" name="cols" id="cols"/></label><br/>
<input name="generate" type="button" value="Create Table!" onclick='createTable();'/>
</form>

<div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How it should look

[image: dynamic table]

Comment: tables are block level, please show your css and generated html

Comment: It looks as though you are missing a curly bracket to close one of your inner for loops.

Comment: `as I have set the CSS that way` have you? Then show us the CSS too!

Comment: @MattBurland sorry copied the wrong version, css is in now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It resets the table it created to the new table in current iteration in this line:

```
document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;
```

You have to do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML += theader + tbody + tfooter;
```

In addition to your comment:

```
var colStart = num_cols / num_super;
```

Should mabe be:

```
var colStart = num_cols * num_super;
```

Comment: Or .append() can add to the html

Comment: @SpykeBytes I'm not familiar with this native JavaScript `.append()`

Comment: @Paul S. It is within jQuery, not native.

Comment: @th3falc0n that fixed the current problem so +1, however now it is echoing table 1-6 twice and 7-12 once, rather than each once. any ideas? if not i appreciate your help.

Comment: Added a suggestion to the answer